# MPMoviePlayer button overlay not responding in iPhone SDK4.0

Tags: iphone, ios4

Do you know how to get a working button overlayed on MPMoviePlayerController.  This was working in SDK 3.x.  The button displays but is not responding to touches.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 4.0 Apple introduced the MPMoviePlayerViewController which is basically a UIView subclass that aggregates an MPMOviePlayerController Object (the property is called `moviePlayer`).

It's very easy now to add custom overlays on top of your movieplayer (because it's a UIView Subclass now).

simply try doing the following

1) create an Instance of an MPMoviePlayerViewController 
2) add it (as a Subview) ontop of your UIView of choice 
3) create and init your overlay (in your case a simple button i guess) 
4) add it (as a Subview) ontop of your MPMoviePlayerViewControllers's `view` Property

hope I could help.

*sam